# ucfirst after comma separated value

Tags: php, ucfirst

I have the value like `admin,bli`

I have used this code to make the first letter capital

```
<?php ucfirst('admin,bli'); ?>
```

And my result is `Admin,bli`

My expected output is

`Admin,Bli`

How can I achieve this without using explode function and a for loop?

Comment: Using a regexp that searches for letters after a comma, with a callback

Comment: how can i do that ? and its dynamic value too

Comment: ucfirst only accept one param i don't think its possible without explode and implode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
    echo join(',', array_map('ucfirst', explode(',', 'bill,jim')));
?>
```

Explode by comma, map `ucfirst` every item using `array_map` and implode it back by `join` or `implode`.

I know you'd like to avoid explode, but its probably quicker than `preg_replace_callback` anyway.

Comment: Was about to post the same using `implode`, the synonym of `join`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace_callback()`:

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/[^,]*/", function($m) {
    return ucfirst($m[0]); 
}, $str);
```

The pattern searches for a lower cased letter after a word boundary and replaces it by it's uppercased version.

An alternative would be to use `array_reduce()`:

```
echo array_reduce(explode(',', $str), function($a, $b) {
    return $a ? $a . ',' . ucfirst($b) : ucfirst($b);
});
```

Comment: thanks but i think above answer is easy to understand :) i can put ^

Comment: smart reduce, forgot bout that :)

Comment: yeah, it saves you the `implode()`